# Как запустить рекламу адмоба(видео) при старте приложения?

Tags: java, android, admob, activity-life-cycle

Ссылка на офф. документацию : https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial

Сделал как там все описано - работает, но только при нажатии кнопки. А как сделать, что бы при каждом запуске приложения отображалась реклама 1 раз?

Comment: Метки (теги) нужны для того, чтобы выделить основные моменты ВОПРОСА, по которым другие пользователи быстрее смогут найти решение аналогичной проблемы, а не для демонстрации собственных предпочтений в выборе IDE. Вопрос никак не связан с проблемами при работе IDE Android Studio и этот тег в вопросе не нужен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Надо отследить что пользователь открыл приложение, а не (например) повернул. Это можно сделать проверив `if(savedInstanceState==null)` это аргумент в `onCreate` методе активити. После её поворота (пересоздания) этот аргумент уже не `null` и условие выполнено не будет.
2. В этом условии сформировать запрос к `AdMob`
3. Запустить его и ждать пока реклама не отобразится.

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
   {
       boolean adsAlredyShown = false;
       InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
           Log.i("LOG", "onCreate");
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
           mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"); //идентификатор из доков надо заменить на свой
           mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener()
           {
               @Override
               public void onAdClosed()
               {
                   Log.i("LOG", "onAdClosed");
               }

               public void onAdLeftApplication()
               {
                   Log.i("LOG", "onAdLeftApplication");
               }

               @Override
               public void onAdLoaded()
               {
                   Log.i("LOG", "onAdLoaded");
                   mInterstitialAd.show();
               }

               public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode)
               {
                   Log.e("LOG", "onAdFailedToLoad with errorCode " + errorCode);
               }
               @Override
               public void onAdOpened()
               {
                   Log.i("LOG", "onAdOpened");
                   //вызывается в момент отображения рекламы.
                   //и раз она отобразилась ставим флаг в true
                   //чтобы больше её не показывать
                   adsAlredyShown = true;
               }
           });

           if(savedInstanceState==null)
           {
               AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
               mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
           }
           else
           {
               adsAlreadyShown = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("AdsAlreadyShown", false);
               //реклама ещё не показывалась
               if(!adsAlreadyShown)
               {
                   AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                   mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
               }
           }
       }

       protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
       {
           super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
           outState.putBoolean("AdsAlreadyShown", adsAlreadyShown);
       }
   }
   ```

---

Также, в тот же `savedInstanceState` можно поместить флаг после показа рекламы и не показывать её пока он `true`. Этот флаг исчезнет только если активити будет убита системой или вручную методом `finish()`

Comment: допишите плис код про флаг (я непонимаю как поместить флаг)?

Comment: @Андрей, это вам не обязательно делать. И без этого должно работать.

Comment: @Андрей, а так флаг - это просто boolean записанный в Bundle в методе onSaveInstanceState и извлекаемый в onCreate из аргумента. Всё это легко гуглится. А ставить его надо в слушателе рекламы в методе, коий вызывается после её показа/перехода юзера по ссылке в ней. Всё это есть в доках AdMob-a

Comment: спасибо большое ВЫ ВСЕГДА ПОМАГАЕТЕ! РЕСПЕКТ))

Comment: @Андрей, пожалуйста) Только учтите, что в случае, если вы повернёте экран до отображения рекламы она не покажется больше до полного перезапуска. Решить это можно вторым способом. Но сегодня уже не допишу - может завтра. Но это легко загуглить.

Comment: пожалуйста допишите так как информация может поможет людям в будущем

Comment: @Андрей, ближе к ночи добавлю

Comment: можете написать весь код отображения рекламы.. я уже второй день сиджу немогу. Немогу икак зделать соединить етот код и с офф сайта без лишнего... просто только оставить рекламу при запуске и выкинуть при нажатии кнопки и все остальной мусор??

Comment: @Андрей, ну, я дополнил, но мне совсем не понятно что в этом непонятного)

Comment: реклама не отображается!

Comment: а что в макете должно быть? setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: @Андрей, наверное надо было её ещё показать после загрузки) Добавил код)

Comment: БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО

Answer (score 4):

Дык, по правилам Гугла, рекламу **Запрещено** отображать при старте приложения ?

[Недопустимые способы размещения межстраничных объявлений](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=ru&ref_topic=2745287)

Comment: сразу после запуска нельзя, но, к примеру, после SplashScreen можно. Т.к. юзер уже будет знать, что это запустилось приложение его.